# correcting certain common values in the list in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

Here's a sample csv file:

```
out_gate,in_gate,n_con
/a_a,b,1
/a_a,b,3
/a_b,a,2
/a_b,c,4
/a_c,a,5
/a_c,b,5
/b_c,a,4
/b_d,c,2
```

From this file's first column's out_gate values I want to filter out only those that starts with '/a_' and then delete their '/a_' prefixes so that I will be left with a new csvfile: (assuming there are actually more than 30 rows)

```
out_gate,in_gate,n_con
a,b,1
a,b,3
b,a,2
b,c,4
c,a,5
c,b,5
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is an ambiguous statement of intent. What is your question? What have you tried and what are your difficulties?

Comment: I have succeeded in sorting out the values that starts with '/a' but stuck at sorting out deleting the letter '/a' and make into new csv file

Comment: Please show your existing code as an edit in the original post

Comment: you write a csv with the csv module, same as reading one, as for deleting read about list comprehensions

Comment: I was just wondering if there exists any function that corrects common values of whole values of the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make a dictionary out of the csv file:

```
import csv 

def from_csv_to_dict():

   reader = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_FILE_NAME)) #the file
   result = {} # will be the dict to retrun

   for row in reader:
       key = row.pop("the id column") # "out_gate" in your case
       result[key] = row

   return result
```

run it and see the result dictionary, it will be a lot easier to do what you want to do with the csv file, after you load the file into a dictionary.

EDIT:

This is the result dictionary that this function will return on your file:

```
{'/b_c': {'in_gate': 'a', 'n_con': '4'}, '/a_a': {'in_gate': 'b', 'n_con': '3'}, '/b_d': {'in_gate': 'c', 'n_con': '2'}, '/a_c': {'in_gate': 'b', 'n_con': '5'}, '/a_b': {'in_gate': 'c', 'n_con': '4'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to do it:

```
from csv import reader, writer

lines = []

csv_reader = reader(open(INPUT_CSV_FILE, 'r'))
for i, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
    if i == 0:
        lines.append(line)
        continue  
    if not line[0].startswith('/a_'):
        continue
    lines.append([line[0][3:], line[1], line[2]])

csv_writer = writer(open(OUTPUT_CSV_FILE, 'w'))
for l in lines:
    csv_writer.writerow(l)
```